# AngularJS wait until element is fully loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, pdftron

I am currently working on a pdftron implementation and it looks like the webviewer is not loaded fast enough at the point when webviwer tries to load the document. How would you set some kind of ready element so it waits until the webViewer is ready to load a document?.

```
    viewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        path: 'WebViewer',
        type: 'html5',
        documentType: 'pdf'
    }, element);

    $scope.watch('url', function(blobVal) {
      viewer.loadDocument(blobVal);
    }
```

I am getting an undefined on viewer.loadDocument and its because viewer is not fully loaded. It happens intermittently.

Answer (score 2):

You want to wait for the WebViever ready event. Please see the guide below:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/fundamentals/webviewer#details-of-instantiation

```
var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
  initialDoc: 'mydoc.pdf',
  ui: 'legacy'
}, viewerElement);

viewerElement.addEventListener('ready', function() {
  // API functions are now ready to be called on myWebViewer
});
```

Please also see the following link:
https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/PDFTron.WebViewer.html#event:ready__anchor

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code makes more sense

```
   $scope.viewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        path: 'WebViewer',
        type: 'html5',
        documentType: 'pdf'
    }, element);

    $scope.$watch('viewer', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal instanceof Blob && newWal !== oldVal) {
        viewer.loadDocument(newVal);
      }
    }
```

Comment: problem is that i also need to watch for url because when the url field changes it loads a new document. I see what you mean about watching for viewer but what about the url, would i need two watches?

Comment: @jedgard I updated the answer, just added check that `newVal !== oldVal`

Comment: The issue with this answer, is that viewer might still not be loaded/ready even after the $watch callback is triggered. So calling viewer.loadDocument could still throw an exception. Not sure what the $watch does, but at the very least you would also need to listen to the WebViewer ready event. See @Yasser answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript timeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
       // You can write functions that will load after Angular elements.
},500);
```

Comment: Should wait for an event, not hard coded timeout. Potentially, say bad latency and very slow/busy device, you could surpass the timeout time, so there would still be a random bug happening. This just makes it less likely, at the cost of arbitrary/needless wait time.